# Incorrect syntax near 'a6552'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Query:

```
delete Emp_Shift_Dtls where ROW_ID = @inROW_ID
```

Execution:

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @ou_Remarks nvarchar(4000),
        @ou_intRetValue int


EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[procEmployeeShiftDetails]
        @DMLType = N'D',
        @inROW_ID = 348a6552-1bf1-4e52-9386-88f04ad9bac4,
        @ou_Remarks = @ou_Remarks OUTPUT,
        @ou_intRetValue = @ou_intRetValue OUTPUT

SELECT  @ou_Remarks as N'@ou_Remarks',
        @ou_intRetValue as N'@ou_intRetValue'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Here `@inROW_ID` is a `uniqueidentifier`. I am unable to execute the query it shows the error like incorrect syntax in `@inROW_ID`

Comment: @inROW_ID = '348a6552-1bf1-4e52-9386-88f04ad9bac4'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing quotes in below pointed statement. It's a string literal and thus require quoting `'`

```
@inROW_ID = '348a6552-1bf1-4e52-9386-88f04ad9bac4'
```

Comment: but it is a int

Comment: @ManasaJ, I don't see that declaration. Moreover, if it's `INT` then the value you are assigning is wrong type. Value you are assigning is a GUID or UUID which is of string type and not INT type.